# passing a text string and a variable into into href selector

Tags: jquery

I need to pass a string AND a variable as a selector into a href attribute, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Can anybody help?

I currently have a variable 'gallery' which I need to pass in the something like:

```
$('#work_gallery li a[href="http://www.ddbremedy.co.uk/siteupdate/" + gallery + ]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the selector to use double quotes so you can use single quotes within the attribute selector.

```
$("#work_gallery li a[href='http://www.ddbremedy.co.uk/siteupdate/" + gallery + "']");
```

Unless you have multiple links to the same page the first part of the selector, `#work_gallery li` may be unnecessary.  If this link only appears once on the page use:

```
 $("a[href='http://www.ddbremedy.co.uk/siteupdate/" + gallery + "']");
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jFYGM/

Comment: @user1391152 Check your markup to make sure the selector matches.  I have included an example to demonstrate that it is working.

Comment: Brilliant. Cheers buddy, you're a star.

Comment: @user1391152 Haha, can you forward that to my boss j/k?  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Like so -

```
$('#work_gallery li a[href="http://www.ddbremedy.co.uk/siteupdate/' + gallery + '"]');
```